# How to import Google Sheets Data Into MongoDB from any link?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, google-sheets-api, mern

### Context

I'm a web development beginner building a MERN stack web-app to help school clubs manage applicants. I want users to be able to input a link to Google Sheet generated from their Google Form and be able to see a cleaner, properly formatted version of their data.

### Exploration

From my research, it looks like most solutions:

- Involve people wanting to automate their **own** sheets (and therefore being able to use the Google Sheets script editor)
- Make use of Tabletop.js, which will soon be deprecated. I looked into PapaParse but really couldn't figure out how to solve my problem using it.
- Use MongoDB Stitch, which also relies on accessing the Google Sheets script editor
- Require users to download the file as a CSV file (which is non-ideal for live updates)

It also seems like the Google Sheets API requires the user to have access to the script editor? I might not be interpreting the docs correctly. Would having users authenticate/login to my web app through Google be able to overcome this problem?

### My Goal

1. User pastes the link to their Google Sheets (with view access or published to the web) in my React app
2. My React app parses the Sheets data and stores it in MongoDB Atlas
3. [Optional] Update the MongoDB database whenever the original sheet is updated (There is no need for MongoDB to communicate back with the sheet.)

Thank you, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So your question is basically how can you use [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) to obtain information from a  Spreadsheet after the user has provided its url right? What do you mean by ```...requires the user to have access to the script editor```?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Yes, you got it right! What I meant by the "script editor" is that a lot of tutorials require you to go into the specific Google Sheets file, then go to **Tools > Script Editor** to input some code. I would not be able to access this just from a url that only has "View" access, for example.

Comment: Would these Sheets from the user be public or private? This is, are they publicly shared or are they private and only the user can access them? Depending on this you would need an implementatation using [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing) asking for permissions to the users or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try out Zapier.

It has a Google Sheets + MongoDB integration.

https://zapier.com/apps/google-sheets/integrations/mongodb

One way you could possibly achieve this is to:

- link your Google Sheets account to Zapier, then
- collect the links through your React app,
- duplicate the sheet from that link
- set Zapier to watch for that trigger when a new sheet is duplicated, to pass on the data to MongoDB